# Ruby on Rails: How do i add new routes inside concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

so I have an app that have 2 module, A and B. Module A and B both can manage pages C and most of their actions is similar, but module B have more action than A. Because they are similar, and the action is not a lot, just normal, I write it in one controller.

The requested link is

```
appname/a/c
appname/b/c
```

Because of that, I write the routes inside a scope

```
scope "/a", as: :a, defaults: {scope: 'a'} do
 resources :c do
   collection do 
     action1
     action2
     action3
   end
 end
end

scope "/b", as: :b, defaults: {scope: 'b'} do
 resources :c do
   collection do 
     action1
     action2
     action3
     action4
     action5
     action6
   end
 end
end
```

As you see, I write the route twice, so I change it and use concern and it became like this

```
concern :c do 
  resources :c do
   collection do
    action1
    action2
    action3
   end
  end
end

scope "/a", as: :a, defaults: {scope: 'a'} do
  concerns :c
end

scope "/b", as: :b, defaults: {scope: 'b'} do
 concerns :c
 get "c/action4"
 post "c/action5"
 post "c/action6"
end
```

What I want to ask is, Can we make it so that the action placed inside the concern block. Is there a way to add a route to an already defined concern? so the concern call become

```
 concerns :c do
  collection do
    action4
    action5
    action6
  end
 end
```

or something like that.

In the documentation we can pass a parameter to concern, can I use that to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.